# How to calculate the list of list and return list of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to calculate the slope of each grid, the logic is this:
horizontal gradient: the left height of the grid minus the right height of the grid 
vertical gradient: the upper height of the grid minus the lower height of the grid
Return: the square root of the sum of both square of both horizontal and vertical gradient.

However, I am unable to calculate the list of 3 lists, and return list of floats.

```
#calculate slope main program 
def find_slope(map_of_heights, x, y):
    ind_row = len(map_of_heights)-1
    ind_column = len(map_of_heights[0])-1

    if y in range(1, ind_column) and x in range(1, ind_row):
        #main logic
        dx = map_of_heights[y][x-1] - map_of_heights[y][x+1]
        dy = map_of_heights[y+1][x] - map_of_heights[y-1][x]

    #different cases when the point is at the edge     
    elif x == 0 and y != 0 and y!= ind_row:
        dx = 0 - map_of_heights[y][x+1]
        dy = map_of_heights[y+1][x] - map_of_heights[y-1][x]
    elif y == 0 and x != 0 and x != ind_column:
        dx = map_of_heights[y][x-1] - map_of_heights[y][x+1]
        dy = map_of_heights[y+1][x] - 0
    elif x == ind_column and y != 0 and y!= ind_row:
        dx = map_of_heights[y][x-1] - 0
        dy = map_of_heights[y+1][x] - map_of_heights[y-1][x]
    elif y == ind_row and x != 0 and x != ind_column:
        dx = map_of_heights[y][x-1] - map_of_heights[y][x+1]
        dy = 0 - map_of_heights[y-1][x]
    elif x == 0 and y == 0:
        dx = 0 - map_of_heights[y][x+1]
        dy = map_of_heights[y+1][x] - map_of_heights[0][x]
    elif x == ind_column and y == 0:
        dx = map_of_heights[y][x-1] - 0
        dy = map_of_heights[y+1][x] - 0
    elif x == 0 and y == ind_row:
        dx = 0 - map_of_heights[y][x+1]
        dy = 0 - map_of_heights[y-1][x]
    elif x == ind_column and y == ind_row:
        dx = map_of_heights[y][x-1] - 0
        dy = 0 - map_of_heights[y-1][x]
    return math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
```

```
#the test height maps
test_maps = [
        [[0, 1, 2], 
         [2, 10, 4], 
         [3, 4, 5]],
        [[10, 1, 2], 
         [2, 3, 4], 
         [3, 4, 5]],
        [[0, 1, 2], 
         [2, 3, 4], 
         [3, 4, 10]],
        [[0, 1, 10], 
         [2, 3, 10], 
         [3, 4, 10]]]
```

For example, at the above test_maps, when x = 1 and y = 1, for the first grid,

```
[[0, 1, 2], 
[2, 10, 4], 
[3, 4, 5]]]
```

the value I am selecting is 10, and therefore the value on the left is 2, on the right is 4, lower is 4, upper is 1.
Then apply the formula sqrt((left - right)**2 + (lower - upper)**2), 3.605551275463989 as the outcome.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

```
#test case
find_slope(test_maps, 1, 1)
```

```
#expected output
[3.605551275463989, 3.605551275463989, 3.605551275463989, 8.54400374531753]
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `x` and `y` ? Can you add an example along with the explanation to get the result you want! Also `map_of_heights[*][*]` is a list, and you are trying to subtract two lists!

Comment: I have added the test case, x=1, y=1

Comment: Also add an example along with the explanation which comes to the result you want! @BKCN

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh ok, I have updated an example to explain how it works. For example, at the above test_maps, when x = 1 and y = 1, for the first grid, 
[[0, 1, 2], 
[2, 10, 4], 
[3, 4, 5]]]
the value I am selecting is 10, and therefore the value on the left is 2, on the right is 4, lower is 4, upper is 1.
Then apply the formula sqrt((left - right)**2 + (lower - upper)**2), 3.605551275463989 as the outcome.

Comment: Same formula and technique applies for all metrices @BCKN?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yea, it applies to all matrices.

Comment: and if x,y lies such that they are in a corner, how to you calculate left right up down etc

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh that's why I have written numbers of if elif cases when the point is the edge.

Comment: Those aren’t really readable, could you add an example or two please @BCKN ?

Answer (score 0):

As error says, you can't subtract two Lists using '-' operator unless you overwrite / overload `__sub__` method. But there is a simpler way that can do that:

```
f = lambda a, b: [a[i]-b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> f(a, b)
[-3, -3, -3]
```

Answer (score 0):

As Javadmk already pointed out, you cannot simply subract lists with the - operator.
If you want to execute an operation like that on a list element by element, I would suggest using numpy, as it supports such operations out of the box.

Going with Javadmk's solution yielded another error for me, since the following line does not support operations on lists: `return math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)`

If you add this line to your imports:

```
import numpy as np
```

And replace your list initialization as follows:

```
test_maps = np.array([[[0, 1, 2], [2, 10, 4], [3, 4, 5]], [[10, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]], [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 10]],  [[0, 1, 10], [2, 3, 10], [3, 4, 10]]])
```

And the calulation of the square root as follows:

```
return np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
```

Then your code will yield a result. It is not the one you expect though, so you probably have some logic error in your code somewhere.